# Отсортировать сумму двух ячеек

Tags: sql

[image]

Есть такая таблица. Мне надо сосчитать кол-во referal_id у каждого referal_owner. Тоесть, у 117 овнера будет 2 referal_id.

После надо их отсортировать в порядке возрастания

Comment: Считайте, сортируйте. В чём вопрос-то?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Я не знаю, как в данной ситуации делать SUM

Answer (score 0):

Делаете [объединение](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)) с этой же таблицей по равенству `referal_id` и `referal_owner`, а потом агрегацию:

```
select
  r.referal_id as owner,
  count(o.referal_owner) as referals
from some_table r
left join some_table o
  on r.referal_id = o.referal_owner
group by r.referal_id;
```

Comment: а разве просто GROUP BY referal_owner и COUNT(referal_id) не подойдет?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(referal_id) as count_referal_id, referal_owner
FROM  some_table 
GROUP BY referal_owner
ORDER BY count_referal_id ASC;
```

Comment: В выборке не появятся те owner'ы, у которых нет рефералов.

Comment: то есть те где поле referal_owner пустое? да, тогда они будут все в одной групе. Я не вникал в этот вариант

Comment: Нет, я про тех, для кого вообще нет соответствующих записей в таблице. В данном примере записи с referal_id 113 и 119 в результатах не появятся.

Comment: так их и не нужно вроде получать, нужно получить поле referal_owner и его количество в таблице (то есть 2) или я неверно понял вопрос

Comment: Ну, этот момент автор не уточнил, но я бы ожидал явных нолей.